# Append not adding to list C#

Tags: c#, append

```
for(int i = 1; i != amount+1; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What is the name of the {0} person?", i);
                people.Append(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("What was their grade?");
                grades.Append(Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine()));
            }
```

(This section is what is affected)

It gets the inputs from the user (I.E. it gets the names and grades, though it doesn't add to the array. I am new to C#, coming from python. Do you guys have any idea how I could fix this issue? TIA

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: Your code is not complete. It is not clear what are the types of `people` and `grades`. `doesn't add to the array` how do you confirm this? What problem you are trying to solve with this code?

Comment: Just like @Chetan Ranpariya said, it will be nice to know the types of these two arrays and as well how U initialized them and the value of amount too.

Comment: As @ChetanRanpariya mentions, you won't get an answer to your question if we don't know the types of `people` and `grades`.  You don't add to a list with `Append`, you add to a list with `List<T>.Add(T)`.  When I see `Append` with a string parameter, I guess that `people` is a `StringBuilder` instance.  You also need to characterize what _"this issue"_ is.  Does your code compile?  Does it run and do something you don't expect?  Does it throw an exception?  Remember that questions with [mcve]s are the ones that get the best answers.  Yours is minimal, but far from complete or reproduceable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;


int amount = 5;
List<string> people = new List<string>();
List<decimal> grades = new List<decimal>();
for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
Console.WriteLine("What is the name of the {0} person?", i);
people.Add(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("What was their grade?");
grades.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine()));
}
```

Comment: @Z0X:  Were you just looking for the method name `Add`?  Where did you get `Apend` from?  Did you look at the documentation _at all_?  If you have a compilation error, then you should mention that, and you should include the text of the error message and the line that it occurs at.  You had a fair about of good talent trying to guess what your problem is - without any clues at all.  You got very lucky that someone was able to guess right.  They next time, include enough information for folk: types, error messages, locations of errors, etc.